# Image is not being shown in OpenCV in Qt

Tags: c++, image, qt, opencv, image-processing

I am new to OpenCV and using it in Qt Creator. I want to display an image. My code is:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( )
{
    Mat image=imread("C:/Users/richa/Desktop/IMG-20150324-WA0001.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); // Read the file


    if( image.empty() )                      // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Image",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Image", image );                // Show our image inside it.

    waitKey(); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

Output is only a console window with no image. Also the program exits with code -1073741511. Why the image is not being loaded in a new window?
Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: The problem could be that you are running the program in a external terminal. Just configure your QtCreator to disable it in `Check Projects -> Run Settings -> Run in terminal`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
int main( )
{
    Mat image=imread("C:/Users/richa/Desktop/IMG-20150324-WA0001.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); // Read the file


    if( image.empty() )                      // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Image",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // Create a window for display.

    for(;;)//infinite loop
    {
    imshow( "Image", image );                // Show our image inside it.

    char c=waitKey(10); // Wait for a keystroke in the window for 10ms, then move on
    if(c=='b' || c=='B')//if b is pressed
    break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```